# Параметры для RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

При `RandomForestClassifier` при подаче в обучение `fit(X, y)`, `X`-это значения признаков, `y` - метки класса.
А вот в `RandomForestRegressor` `X` и `y`, что они означают?

```
z=np.array([70862.5000,70550.0000,70050.0000,67637.5000,67987.5000,69575.0000,69275.0000,67225.0000])#цены 
F=z.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В задачах регрессии предсказываются числа (например цена). Соответственно `y` - это вектор искомых чисел из **обучающей** выборки.

---

Пример из реальной жизни - ["Housing Values in Suburbs of Boston" AKA Kaggle "Boston Housing"](https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing).

В данном датасете есть следующие признаки (столбцы):

- `crim` - per capita crime rate by town.
- `zn` - proportion of residential land zoned for lots over 25,000 sq.ft.
- `indus` - proportion of non-retail business acres per town.
- `chas` - Charles River dummy variable (= 1 if tract bounds river; 0 otherwise).
- `nox` - nitrogen oxides concentration (parts per 10 million).
- `rm` - average number of rooms per dwelling.
- `age` - proportion of owner-occupied units built prior to 1940.
- `dis` - weighted mean of distances to five Boston employment centres.
- `rad` - index of accessibility to radial highways.
- `tax` - full-value property-tax rate per $10,000.
- `ptratio` - pupil-teacher ratio by town.
- `black` - 1000(Bk - 0.63)^2 where Bk is the proportion of blacks by town.
- `lstat` - lower status of the population (percent).

и наконец искомый признак:

- `medv` - median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000s.

Для данного датасета `X` - это все признаки / столбцы, кроме искомого `medv`, `y` - `medv`.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю тогда X это индексы(к примеру есть ряд из 10 значений, значит значения имеют индексы от 0 до 9)?

Comment: @user287629, `X` - это матрица входных данных (значения признаков), на основании которых делаются предсказания

Comment: Добавил немного кода. Там F это цены в нужном формате для "scikit-learn". Что будет X , а что y, в данном случае? И как сделать предсказание в будущее больше чем, на одно значение?

Comment: И все-таки я не силен в терминологии, если y это значения(например цена), значит X это индексы, в моем случае. Но X может и быть любым другим признаком предсказывающим y?

Comment: `X` - это как `x` в обычной функции `y = f(x)`. Т.е. это то что подается функции на вход, `y` - результат работы функции для переменной `x`. Я не совсем понимаю что вы понимаете под индексами... `X` - это входные данные, `y` - результат работы предсказанной функции если ей передать на вход `X`

Comment: Имелось ввиду, если в моем случае есть только значение цен и больше ничего. Это, как в ARIMA, когда делается прогноз в будущее исходя из предыдущих значений.

Comment: @user287629, если вы о Time Series, то Random Forest вам здесь врядли поможет. Попробуйте ARIMA, SARIMA и т.д.

Comment: Я еще не знаю, как выразится, чтобы понятно было. Вот есть массив F, что в вопросе. Покажите, как предсказать следующее значение этого массива.

Comment: @user287629, я с Time Series пока не работал. Из того что слышал - сначала надо определиться с переодичностью ряда. Потом разбираться с сезонностью и т.д. В общем я здесь врядли помогу...

Comment: Я сделал так: подаю значения цен в "X" со сдвигом назад на один, а в "y" подаю без сдвига. Но, что-то больно радужно все получается.

Comment: @user287629, чтобы проверить разбейте на обучающую и тестовые выборки - 15-20% данных в конце - это для тестов, то что в начале для обучения